# Can rxjs control the maximum frequency of a function call?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rxjs, react-native-flatlist

I am making a react-native app. Since the onEndReached props in FlatList is problematic, onEndReached can be triggered more than once when the end is reached.

I have heard of rxjs that can make a button's onPress only be triggered once with some condition even user is clicking on it multiple times.

Below is the `Flatlist`:

```
<FlatList
    data={paginatedList}
    ListHeaderComponent={() => this.renderHeader()}
    renderItem={({item, index}) => this.renderItem(item, index)}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0}
    onEndReached={(distanceFromEnd) => {
        console.log(distanceFromEnd); 
        this.setState({normalListLength: normalListLength + 10})
    }}
/>
```

I want the `this.setState` function to be limited to once per seconds (1000ms) . Is that I should use rxjs to do this?

Comment: [debounce](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debounce.html) is what you are looking for

Comment: Yes, but i am not sure how to apply it to my case. I have never used rxjs before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one possible solution could be to have a Subject which you can *next()* the new value (distanceFromEnd) into. And then you can apply any combination of operators (including debounceTime) to enforce the frequency limiting.

*Keep in mind my React syntax might not be spot on*

```
<FlatList
  data={paginatedList}
  ListHeaderComponent={() => this.renderHeader()}
  renderItem={({item, index}) => this.renderItem(item, index)}
  onEndReachedThreshold={0}
  onEndReached={(distanceFromEnd) => {
    console.log(distanceFromEnd); 
    myOnEndReachedSubject.next(distanceFromEnd);
    this.setState({normalListLength: normalListLength + 10})
  }}
/>

// elsewhere define subject
myOnEndReachedSubject = new Subject<number>();

// ....elsewhere in a lifecycle function  
componentDidMount() {

  myOnEndReachedSubject
    .debounceTime(1000) // debounce for a second
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe((distance) => {
       // Do something with distance
       // setState etc
    });
}
```